# How to get selector name as an attribute on an object in Swift?

Tags: swift, selector

When working with rest JSON-APIs its convenient to keep usage of an attribute consistent throught the app and when calling the server
For this example:

```
class Picture: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var copyright: String
    @NSManaged var likes: NSNumber
}


func postToServer() {
   let newPicture = Picture(copyright: "haaakon", likes:433)

   let arguments = @{  
       newPicture.copyright.selectorName : newPicture.copyright,
       newPicture.likes.selectorName : newPicture.likes 
   }

   println(arguments)
}
```

println should give this output:

```
{ "copyright": "haaakon", "likes": "433" }
```

How to go about when creating an extension (or other solution) on a given attribute that returns basically the same as:

```
NSStringFromSelector(Selector(newPicture.copyright)) // returns "copyright"
newPicture.copyright.selectorName                    // returns "copyright"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension Picture{
    func dictionary() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        var outCount: CUnsignedInt = 0
        let properties: UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(self.dynamicType, &outCount)

        var result: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = Dictionary()

        for var i = 0; i < Int(outCount); i++ {
            var property : NSString! = NSString(CString: property_getName(properties[i]), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            result[property] = self.valueForKey(property)
        }

        return result
    }
}
```